# Notification Action not firing PendingIntent

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin

I want to create a Notification that displays a download progress (it is mocked for now) and allows the user to cancel the download. I use the Notification Builder and add the 'cancel download' action. The action is displayed, but it does not send the PendingIntent on click. I confirmed that the PendingIntent is working by setting the contentIntent. The broadcast receiver is able to get the message of the content click, but not of the action click.

[image]

**DownloadService**

```
val cancelIntent = Intent(applicationContext, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
    action = "xxx.xxx.xxx.CANCEL_DOWNLOAD"
    putExtra("notification_id", NOT_ID_PROGRESS)
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 1, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

pendingIntent.send()

val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "updates").apply {
    setContentTitle("Title")
    setContentText("Text")
    setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_full_black)
    setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
    setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    addAction(NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_delete, "Cancel", pendingIntent).build())
}
startForeground(NOT_ID_PROGRESS, notificationBuilder.build())

Thread({
    for (i in 0..100) {
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, i, false)
        notificationManager?.notify(NOT_ID_PROGRESS, notificationBuilder.build())
        Thread.sleep(100L)
    }
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false)
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download completed")
    notificationManager?.notify(NOT_ID_COMPLETE, notificationBuilder.build())
    onFinish()
}).start()
```

**NotificationBroadcastReceiver**

```
class NotificationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val notificationId = intent?.getIntExtra("notification_id", 0) ?: 0
        Log.d(TAG, "NotificationBroadcastReceiver: notificationId = $notificationId")
        (context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?)?.cancel(notificationId)
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".services.DownloadService" />
<receiver
    android:name=".services.PackageDownloadService$NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.CANCEL_DOWNLOAD" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. First of all, everything was configured right. The only thing I had to change was the update interval of the notification. After setting the interval to about **2000ms**, the click event was fired when selecting the abort action button.

```
Thread({
    for (i in 0..100 step 20) {
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, i, false)
        notificationManager?.notify(NOT_ID_PROGRESS, notificationBuilder.build())
        Thread.sleep(2000L)
    }
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false)
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download completed")
    notificationManager?.notify(NOT_ID_COMPLETE, notificationBuilder.build())
    onFinish()
}).start()
```